# How to create a custom button and use multiple times in best way in Watch Kit?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am new to watch app development.Can any one tell me sample for creating custom button i.e used for multiple classes in watch kit. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ Damiaan Dufaux: that means common class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't create a custom button directly in WatchKit, however you can do it with SpriteKit or SceneKit.